# Clear my Listbox after a Ajax POST

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, post

I am displaying a list of information in a ListBox using JQuery and Ajax post. I actually select a value in another Listbox1, click my button and then it displays in another ListBox2 information accordingly to the value I have selected in my ListBox1.

But when i select another value from the Listbox1, I want to remove/replace the information that are in my Listbox2. In my code, it keeps adding the information.

I need to clear my Listbox2 when I click again on my button!

Here's my code:

```js
 $('#btnList').click(function () {
    var list = {
        "ContainerName": $("#listContainer option:selected").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:49416/AzureService.svc/ListBlob",
        data: JSON.stringify(list),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processData: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                $('#listBlob').append($('<option>').text(value).val(index));
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `.empty()` it before appending:

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#listBlob').empty(); // <---- clear all other prev options added.
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $('#listBlob').append($('<option>').text(value).val(index));
    });
},
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly :)